# How can I set the width of dropdown_field in Blockly?

Tags: css, width, dropdown, blockly, google-blockly

The block is long because there are too many characters in the dropdown field.

So I want to fix the number of characters or the length of the dropdown field.

[image]

Please give me your advice !

Have a nice day

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger the blocks and check them as you check an input form.
[this is a link to the Documentation page](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/create-custom-blocks/define-blocks#change_listeners_and_validators) .
This link gives you Change Listeners you can use to validate the block or show a warning message